# Lower Triangular Form

Tags: matrices, gaussian-elimination

Suppose that $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix of real numbers such that each entry satisfies $|a_{ij}| \leq 1$.  If Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting is used to reduce the matrix to lower triangular form, show that after $k$ steps of the process, no entry can have magnitude larger that $2^k$.

Can anyone help me with this problem?